# How can I count the number of turns for this coil?

Tags: wireless, coil, winding

I am currently working on a project which deals with wireless power transfer. I am using a few coils to test out from Würth.

The coil in question is the [760308100143](https://www.we-online.com/components/products/datasheet/760308100143.pdf).

I wanted to find the coupling coefficient of this coil, but the coil has about 5 windings and looks to be two layers. What value should I take for the windings? Five, or is it different because of the two layers?

[image]

Edit1:
I know the answer has already been accepted but I had another doubt pertaining to the L of the following coil. The coil below has two wires for each side, also 5 windings per layer, and it has 2 layers. In this case would be 10 windings or would this be more since it has two wires at each end of the coil?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *My questions was what value should I take for the windings? 5 or is it
> different because of the two layers?*

The turns will be ten because, the two winding layers are in series. Of course, if there is a third winding layer, the turns will be 15.